# Sprite direction change when tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite, skaction

I am trying to make a sprite move left when touchesBegan and then move right the next time the user touches.

I have seen some code which I think would work perfectly however I am not too sure how to define "isMovingleft"

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    ship.removeAllActions()

    if isMovingleft == true  {
        let left = SKAction.moveBy(x: 500, y: 0, duration: 5)
        ship.run(left)
    }
    else {
        let right = SKAction.moveBy(x: -500, y: -900, duration: 5)
        ship.run(right)
    }
    isMovingleft = !isMovingleft


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enum Direction: Int {
    case left = 0
    case right
}

var direction: Direction?

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    ship.removeAllActions()

    switch direction ?? .left {
    case .left:
        ship.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 500, y: 0, duration: 5))
        direction = .right
    case .right:
        ship.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: -500, y: -900, duration: 5))
        direction = .left
    }
}
```